# Working with distinct shape inside the UIImage, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-image

I have an array of pixels that describes some sort of shape in the image. (E.G. My image is a cake and I have the location of the pixels for the cherry on the top of the cake.)

What I want to do is to allow the user to draw only inside of that shape. My first suggestion was to check if the touch is inside of the shape and only then join lines but it leads to many complications:

- Between two points might lay some other shapes, in that case, I have
  two divide line into multiple lines and join them only inside the
  initial shape.
- The first point might be inside of the shape and second outside, in
  that case, I have to find the evenly remote point on the bound of the
  shape.

Each shape in code is represented with this class:

(saving pixels as a linear index in array 2048x2048, `bounds` - indices of shape outer line):

```
final class Shape {
    private(set) var set = IndexSet()
    let bounds: [Int]

    func contains(_ point: Int) -> Bool {
        return set.contains(point)
    }

    init(set: IndexSet, bounds: [Int]) {
        self.set = set
        self.bounds = bounds
    }
}
```

So is that possible to render only pixels and draw lines only inside them? Or should I handle all those edge cases that I described above? Thanks.

P.S. Sorry but I'm not a native speaker, so feel free to edit, thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a bit harder... Do I get it right that you are working on pixels (not vector)? So `set` contains all pixels of the image (referenced by their index)? And how do you "join lines"? What are you using to draw?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Yes, right I'm working with pixels. Drawing lines on another view via CGContext and then merging them in the initial view.